# Retrieving HTTP response from curl HTTP into variables

Tags: php, http, variables, curl, header

I am using a cURL in php to submit via SMSGlobals HTTP API and it responds with this on a successful send.

**OK: 0; Sent queued message ID: 941596d028699601 SMSGlobalMsgID:6764842339385521**

My cURL code

```
//open CURL connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set url, variables and post
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $httpsend);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

My issue is I need to extract the initial OK (which is an ERROR if there is an error). Along with the message ID and the SMSGlobalMsgID into variables so I can use them to confirm. I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: There isn't any code in there to parse the return. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Think I figured it out. 
I added this to setting up the url, variables and post part of the code. Returns the variable information then I used php list with ":" as the separator.

    `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` 


And

    `list($variable1,$variable2,$variable3,$variable4) = explode(":", $result);`

Comment: sorry, I was trying to use the list and explode function, but forgot to mention that. What I didn't realise was it was echoing the result and fooling me :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I ended up doing. Hope this helps anyone with similar issues.

```
//open CURL connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set url, variables and post
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $httpsend);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

//Break out response into variables separated by :
list($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = explode(":", $result)
```